# 'Module' object is not callable in langchain

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to build a youtube assistant with the help of langchain and google palm api.

So, when I finally run my code, I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/youtube_assitant/langchain_helper.py", line 62, in <module>
        response, docs = get_response_from_query(vectordb, query)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/youtube_assitant/langchain_helper.py", line 34, in get_response_from_query
        llm = google_palm(google_api_key=os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY"), temperature = 0)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is the entire code:

```
    from langchain.document_loaders import YoutubeLoader
    from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
    from langchain.llms import google_palm
    from langchain.chains import LLMChain
    from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
    from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
    from langchain.embeddings.google_palm import GooglePalmEmbeddings
    import os
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
    load_dotenv()
    
    embeddngs = GooglePalmEmbeddings()
    
    video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxOh12Uhg08"
    
    # create_vectordb_from_youtube_url = cvfyu
    def create_vectordb_from_youtube_url(video_url: str) -> FAISS:
        loader = YoutubeLoader.from_youtube_url(video_url)
        transcript = loader.load()
    
        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size = 1000, chunk_overlap = 100)
        docs = text_splitter.split_documents(transcript)
    
        db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddngs)
        return db
    
    def get_response_from_query(db, query, k=4):
    
    # k is no. of docs that will be create
        docs = db.similarity_search(query, k = k)
        docs_page_content = " ".join([d.page_content for d in docs])
    
        llm = google_palm(google_api_key=os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY"), temperature = 0)
    
        prompt = PromptTemplate(
            input_variables=["question", "docs"],
            template="""
            You are a helpful assistant that that can answer questions about youtube videos 
            based on the video's transcript.
            
            Answer the following question: {question}
            By searching the following video transcript: {docs}
            
            Only use the factual information from the transcript to answer the question.
            
            If you feel like you don't have enough information to answer the question, say "I don't know".
            
            Your answers should be verbose and detailed.
            """,
        )
    
        chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
    
        response = chain.run(question=query, docs=docs_page_content)
        response = response.replace("\n","")
        return response, docs
    
    vectordb = create_vectordb_from_youtube_url(video_url)
    query = "What this video is about?"
    
    response, docs = get_response_from_query(vectordb, query)
    print("Response: ", response)
    print("Docs: ", docs)
```

I have try many methods but nothing workout so far. I tried to google search it too but it didn't work. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?? Thank you.

I was expecting a result to my query as an output but instead I got this TypeError

Answer (score -1):

in your code, you call `google_palm` like a function, which it is not.

I think what you are looking for is langchain.llms.GooglePalm

so, if you change your import of google_palm to this

```py
from langchain.llms import GooglePalm
```

and change line 34 to

```py
        llm = GooglePalm(google_api_key=os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY"), temperature = 0)
```

you should be good